# What is needed to access the written materials in a case?

Tags: england-and-wales, legal-research, any-jurisdiction

County court decisions tend to be public. Some refer to other case documents such as particulars of claim or defence statements etc, sometimes by precise paragraphs.

Suppose a member of the public reading such a decision wishes to see the cited materials submitted by the parties in the case to the court. What world be needed to obtain these?

Answer (score 1):

In the [united-states](/questions/tagged/united-states), you would go to the clerk of courts' website and look up the case. For federal courts, that's [PACER](https://pacer.gov).

For courts that don't put these materials online, you would just walk into the clerk of courts's office, and ask to see the case file, which contains all the documents filed in the case. In my experience, it's exceedingly uncommon for anyone to ask anything further of you before providing these materials.